# Difference between "A flea bit Dog on his ear" and "A flea bit the ear of Dog"?

Tags: meaning

What is the exact difference between "A flea bit Dog on his ear" and "A flea bit the ear of Dog"?
Every time I saw the sentence "A flea bit Dog on his ear," I have often thought it as "Dog is on his ear and a flea bit Dog". Is this wrong?

Comment: This is a common problem with the placement of prepositional phrases in English.  Since a prepositional phrase can modify almost any word in the sentence, the sentence can be syntactically ambiguous, leading to [this famous exchange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfN_gcjGoJo).  The ambiguity must be resolved semantically: dogs don't rest on their ears, elephants don't wear pajamas.

Comment: The original post's examples use "Dog" as a proper noun.  (A proper noun is a name, like "Malvolio" or "Jasper".)  Since "Dog" is a name, the examples do not say what kind of creature Dog is.  Dog might be a dog (*Canis familiaris*) or a human (*Homo sapiens*) or even a cat (*Felis catus*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In term of actual meaning, there is no difference.  It's Dog's ear, and a flea bit it.  The first sentence is a little more fluent and less formal.  If you really wanted to try really hard to interpret them differently, I suppose "bit the ear of Dog" could mean that the ear isn't attached to Dog - it's one that belongs to him but isn't attached to his body, or that was attached to his body but is now severed.  But this is extremely unlikely.

Yes, your interpretation of *"A flea bit Dog on his ear"* is wrong.  *on his ear* doesn't modify *Dog*, but the way in which the flea bit Dog.  To phrase it the way you're thinking of, it would have to be something like "A flea bit Dog, **who was** on his ear."

Comment: When I see the sentence "A flea bit Dog on his ear" I have often thought like this, "A flea bit Dog. Dog is on his ear of something(i.e, lion, tiger, dinosaour etc). The flea bit Dog on his ear".  Like "the vase on the table", I have understood the same way on "Dog on his ear". And I have thought that the sentence would be written that way. Then because the branch is the belongs of the tree, should we answer like this, not "A bird sit on the branch on the tree" but "A bird sit the tree on the branch"?

Comment: @user22046 Don't forget to adjust the verb for the 3rd-person singular: *A bird sits on the tree branch*, *A bird sits on the branch of the tree*, &c. You also can't "sit a tree".

Comment: **sits** is not a transitive verb, @user22046. The verb's transitivity or intransitivity is central to the question you're asking.

Comment: Yes. I change the verb from "sit" to "peck". Then because the branch is the belongs of the tree, should we answer like this, not "A bird pecks on the branch on the tree" but "A bird pecks  the tree on the branch"?

Comment: A bird bit the branch. **Why not branch on the tree? Because branches  usually are part of a tree.** Therefore, a bird bit the branch lying on the ground. Otherwise, just bit the branch.

Comment: If so, is "The branch on the limb, And the limb on the tree, And the tree in a hole, And the hole in the ground" wrong? is "The branch of the limb, And the limb of the tree~" right?====>source: https://www.kididdles.com/lyrics/g012.html

Comment: What is the difference between a tree and a dog? Is the expression of "the branch on the limb, the limb on the tree" possible? Is the expression of "the ear on the dog" wrong?  are both of two expressions wrong?

Comment: @lly  You also can't "sit a tree". - unless you were W.S.Gilbert, who rhymed "strategy" with "sat a gee" (gee = horse). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major-General%27s_Song

Comment: @alephzero Eh, good catch but [that's just a poetic extension of the same old use of *a* for *on* that you see in *afoot*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8). It still doesn't work for trees, which you sit *in* rather than *atop*, even if one were being archaic and poetic.

Comment: @user22046 First, *limbs* and *boughs* are theoretically the larger, firmer *branches* but few to none actually distinguish them. The smaller branches are *twigs* or (uncommon but easily understandable) *branchlets*.

Comment: @user22046 Second, the difference is that *of* and *on* differ in how closely attached the object is. It's much more common to say the *dog's ear*, the *limb of the tree*, &c. Saying "the ear on the dog" implies at worst that there is an unattached ear sitting atop the dog and at best that the dog has only one ear. "One of the ears on the dog" is fine but needlessly verbose and awkward.

Comment: @user22046 As for the "difference" between a tree and a dog: a tree's limbs and branches can be (and often are) detached from the whole in a way a dog's ears can be but usually aren't, given the lack of use for such detached ears and the discomfort it causes the dog.

Comment: @user22046 In any case, you can replace *pecks* with *pecks on* but the way to express your idea is "A bird pecks the tree branch" (*tree* as an adjective clarifying "branch"), "A bird pecks one of the tree's branches" (if you wished to focus upon the feelings of the particular tree), "A bird pecks a branch of the tree" (same idea), or "A bird pecks the tree" (if you wished to solely focus upon the tree).

Comment: "A bird pecks the tree on the branch" is bizarre first for implying that the tree has only one branch and second for treating the tree like an animal instead of a thing. You touch a dog on its ear; you touch a branch of a tree or you touch a tree but it's unusual and poetic personification if you touch a tree upon its branch. I imagine there are some Singerian philosophical implications you could try to "correct" through using your expression as a form of political correctness, but it's still going to sound odd to the rest of us til it catches on.

Answer (score 4):

*Where on the dog* did the flea bite?
--The flea bit the dog *on its ear*.

*What part of the dog's body* did the flea bite?
--The flea bit *the ear* of the dog.

The *semantic* difference is the difference between **where on the dog** and **what body part of the dog**, location versus discrete body part.

The *grammatical* difference:

In "The flea bit the dog on its ear", **the dog** is the direct object of the transitive verb, and **on its ear** is a complement specifying location.

In "The flea bit the ear of the dog", **the ear** is the direct object of the transitive verb, and **of the dog** is a complement specifying ownership or membership, the entity to which the ear belongs, or the collection of body parts of which the ear is a member.

P.S. Since you've asked about placement of the complement...

The placement of the prepositional phrase complement will depend on the transitivity of the verb.

> The flea **sat** on the ear of the dog (or ... sat on the dog's ear)   <sup>intransitive</sup>
>
> The flea **bit** the dog on the ear. <sup>transitive</sup>
>
> The flea **bit** the ear of the dog. <sup>transitive</sup>

Comment: If someone told me "Where on the dog did the flea bite?" If I answer the question, I maybe come to the answer like this,
Not "The flea bit the dog on its ear" But "The flea bit on its ear on the dog." Am I misunderstanding? If we answer like this, "The flea bit on its ear on the dog." Is it wrong?

Comment: The complement *on its ear* would come after the direct object: The flea bit the dog on its ear.   It is ungrammatical to say "The flea bit on its ear the dog".